# Struggle with creating new HashMap functions

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to implement methods from putVal() and getNode() from the original Java 8 JDK HashMap with an ArrayList of nodes but I am having trouble with implementing the separate chaining part. I'm very new at programming.

```
public HashMap3() {
        this.table1 = new ArrayList[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) table1[i] = new ArrayList<>();
      }
     
private V putVal(int hash, K key, V value) {
        ArrayList<Node>[] tab;
        ArrayList<Node> p;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < table1[i].size(); i++) {
            p = table1[i] ;
            if (p.get(i).key.equals(key) || p.get(i).key == key)
                return value;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Node getNode(int hash, Object key) {
        ArrayList<Node>[] tab = new ArrayList[size]; 
        ArrayList<Node> first, e; K k;
        int n = (table1 = resize()).length;
    
        for (int i=0; i < tab[i].size(); i++){
            return table1[hash(key)].get(i);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Java implementation are you referring to? Who is the vendor?

Comment: `ArrayList<Node>[]` is array of list of nodes. I think you need only `ArrayList<Node>` But then you'll have to convert every Node array to `List<Nodes>`.

Comment: the original Java 8 JDK

Comment: Post more details as edits to the Question rather than as comments.